# Getting the text from CSS Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, oracle-apex

Good evening to everybody! I'm still learning HTML and JavaScript and got the following task. I have an Interactive Report in Oracle Apex 4.2.6.0003, in which there is one column that due to its length (over five words) should be got brief. For solving that problem I've come up with using CSS tooltips. The code which is inside of the field looks like this:

```
<div class="inside">
 <a class="tooltip" href="#">
  <span class="preview">The first few words from field....</span>
  <br/>see more
  <span class="hidden">The whole text from field</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

I made the column to have this formatting due to Dynamic Action. And CSS classes used in my code are these:

```
div.inside{
  display: block;
  z-index: 9900
}
span.preview{
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
a.tooltip{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.tooltip span.hidden{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9990;
}
a.tooltip:hover span.hidden{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  padding: 3px 3px 5px 5px;
  width: 45ch;
  height: auto;
  right: 0ch;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(100,100,0);
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

Moreover, for seeing the tooltips I had to write in all the -cells of my IR "overflow: visible" in attribute "style". And all is fine except one imperfection: the text, which lies inside of tag "span" of class "hidden", cannot be selected by means of mouse - I just receive crossed circle instead of any other kind of cursor. I've tried to use the following Javascript code to get workaround:

```
$("a.tooltip").click(function(){
  window.clipboardData.setData('text',$(this).find("span.hidden").html());
  return false;
});
```

but it doesn't work at all - it just does nothing. Besides, I've already read for many times that getting the text to clipboard not in Internet Explorer is almost impossible. But I'm using Firefox and I should write code for this browser, and it is much desirable NOT to change any options concerned with security.

So my question is: what should I do to be able to select the text from my CSS tooltip and get it copied to clipboard?

Comment: So what you want to do is extract the html/ text content from the tooltip and then display it right? Do you want an external button to display the contents of that tooltip into a text area so that you would be able to copy it or you'd like to copy the contents just like that?

Comment: What would really help illustrate the issue to everyone who could help, making a page with this on apex.oracle.com would be extremely helpful. Especially for js or css people checking this out and trying to help, having access to an apex page would likely avoid clearly apex-invalid answers. Just a hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just removed the `href` attribute from the `<a>` tag and created a span class for 'see more'. If you hover on 'see more' a pointer will appear and you will still be able able to copy the contents of the tooltip.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4pnjmd7/)

No js or jquery has been used to enable the copying of the contents of the tooltip. This is a pure css approach.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="inside">
 <a class="tooltip">
  <span class="preview">The first few words from field....</span>
  <br/>
  <!-- JUST ADDED THE CLASS HOVERABLE -->
  <span class = "hoverable">see more</span>
  <span class="hidden">The whole text from field</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.inside{
  display: block;
  z-index: 9900
}
span.preview{
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
a.tooltip{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.tooltip span.hidden{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9990;
}
a.tooltip:hover span.hidden{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  padding: 3px 3px 5px 5px;
  width: 45ch;
  height: auto;
  right: 0ch;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(100,100,0);
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

//ONLY CHANGE MADE TO THE EXISTING CSS
.hoverable{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: No problem @PiggyInTheMirror happy to help :D Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the javascript to

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.tooltip").click(function(){
            var str = $(this).find("span.hidden").text();
                  if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
                clipboardData.setData("Text", str);
            }
        });
    });
```

Please note that the code you've written to copy in clipboard will work in Internet Explorer ONLY. You have to write a cross browser code for it. For security reasons, browsers don't allow it. Please find another workaround.